# What to label digital prints made from scanned negatives in an exhibit?

Tags: film, terminology, prints, scanning

I have my first exhibit coming up but I am not sure about how to properly label my photographs. All the pictures were taken with 35 mm film, then the negatives were scanned and the images were digitally printed. I'd like to highlight the use of film, though I don't want to be misleading and make it sound like I made all the prints in a darkroom. 
I was thinking of something like "print from 35 mm film scan", what do you think? any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something along the lines of "Digital print from 35mm film negative" should sum it up quite well - it clearly states that the original photo was taken on 35mm.

I don't think you need to say that it was scanned. Scanning is I guess the standard way to transfer film negatives to digital format, but obviously there are also other ways, eg a device for holding the negative in front of the camera lens